# how to connect samsung j7 to eclipse to run apk

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, drive

I was installing USB drive and Samsung Kies also i enabled the usb debug at Samsung J7 and the model number is SM-J700H.

and at eclipse i was make target for devices and installed USB drivers but not working and i can't install apk at devices.

this is the steps:
1. Download OEM USB Driver
2. Enable USB Debugging
3. Connect device to PC
4. Eclipse -> Android

but nothing happens

also i used this link 
Samsung Galaxy J7 USB Drivers for Windows

http://www.teamandroid.com/2015/12/01/samsung-galaxy-j7-usb-drivers-download-now/

no result

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your driver installation is succeed
2. in Eclipse Windows -> Show View -> Other -> Devices, check if your device detect or not

Comment: I did all steps  it before i put this issue at StackOverFlow , no result not appear